# Using readonly structs as Dictionary Key

Tags: c#, struct, c#-7.2

I was wondering how readonly structs behave when used a key in a Dictionary. I'm aware the combition of readonly and 'in' is to prevent copies of large structs being made unnecessarily and that the scenario described below is hardly considered 'large'. However I am curious and I want to keep code simple.

For example

```
public readonly struct MyStruct
{
    public int Value1 { get; }
    public int Value2 { get; }

    public MyStruct(int val1, int val2)
    {
        Value1 = val1;
        Value2 = val2;
    }

    //also overries GetHashCode and Equals 
}
```

Now if I was to create a method that took one of these structs and used it's data, because it is marked readonly, I can mark that parameter as an 'in' parameter

```
public int MyMethod(in MyStruct mystruct)
{
    //do stuff
    return 0;
}
```

It is my understanding that doing this stops the struct having a protective copy created to ensure that it is not modified inside the method.

So far so good I hope.

Now to the meat of the question.

What happens when I use a readonly struct as a key in my dictionary?

```
public Dictionary<MyStruct, string> MyDict;
```

when doing

```
var myStruct = new MyStruct(1,2);
mydict.Add(myStruct,"value");
```

Is a copy of my readonly struct made? Since the method signature does not use 'in' for the key parameter.

Also when attempting to do some thing like `TryGetValue`

```
myDict.TryGetValue(myStruct, out var myString);
```

Will this again make a copy of myStruct?

And lastly what about using the index to look up into the Dictionary?

```
var myVal = myDict[myStruct]
```

If copies are made and the primary use case of my struct is to be used as a key is it pointless marking it with the readonly keyword?

Comment: Yes, a copy of the struct is made in all of the cases you ask about.

Comment: Class object in c# create links (pointers) to object and does not make copies.  A Dictionary is a class object and does not make a copy of the original data.

Comment: Note that `in` and `ref readonly` are for parameter passing and result passing up and down the call stack, none of these allow you to make persistent *reference* copies, all those things will have to make actual copies of the structs.

Comment: In other words, you could create a dictionary type that returned `ref readonly` of your struct, but you wouldn't be allowed to store this into a field without making a copy of the struct it refers to. The dictionary, as well, would not be allowed to store references to the original structs and would have to make its own copy.

Comment: It's not "pointless" if it's an immutable struct, like pretty much **all structs should be**. Whenever you store a struct into a field or an array, a copy of your struct must be made, which is what happens at some point inside the dictionary.

Comment: All very useful thanks. If some one wants to post your useful comment as an answer I'll mark it as the answer